# what is the proper way of using an if condition with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to validate a form where the input is the first and last name using regex in PHP. All I need the regex to do is check to make sure that there are no numbers. This is what I have right now:

```
if (preg_match('/\A\b[^0-9]*\W[^0-9]*\b\Z/sm', $name)) {
# Successful match
$nameError = "";
echo $name;
} else {
# Match attempt failed\
$nameError = "No Numbers";
}
```

The $name variable holds First and last name. I have been trying to make this work and I have not been able to get the input to match the regex. Am I using this correctly or do I need to input it in another way. Thank you for your help

Comment: If that were your name, then this code would make sure that you don't have any numbers typed in.

Comment: I just need to check to make sure that there are no numbers added into the names, this is for a class assignment.

Answer (score 1):

if name is surename and first name you should use condition depending on country for example in Poland it would be

```
preg_match('/[a-z]+ [a-z]+/i',$name);
```

It means that all the names that contains two part that are alphabetic with space separating them are good. If you want first letter of name to be upper you should change it to

```
preg_match('/[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+/',$name);
```

Preg_match returns true if $name is validated by regular expression that you provide in the first argument.

So your usage of this function is okay, you should check your expression.

https://www.php.net/preg_match

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

You can always check your regex on online checker for example

http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/

Comment: Why "depending on country"? Do you think all people in Poland have lowercase names?

Comment: why? Because in various countries the name condition may be different for example in Netherland you have name "Rafael Ferdinand van der Vaart" or in some north america countries names like "jose francisco cevallos enriquez" which in Poland are incorrect.

Comment: Why is Jose not allowed to live in Poland? Doesn't van der Vaart live in Germany?

Comment: HAHAHAHA another hilarious comment :D hahahahha love this stackoverflow

Comment: Even chinese man is allowed to live in Poland will you write reg exp to validate his name? Don't go to extremes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want two words separated by one space, this will do what you want: `if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$/', $name))`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your replies, I found the answer in the most obvious place though and it didn't have anything to do with the regex. I forgot to setup the variables correctly for using them on the same page as the form. Stupid mistake. Anyway, thank you again.